# How to concatenate without spaces?

Tags: string, dart, concatenation

Dart provide us a new way to concate strings without the + operator.

Old way would be:

```
    String foo = "foo";
    String newString = "Hello" + " foo " + "bar";
```

The dart way would be:

```
    String foo = "foo";
    String newString = "Hello $foo bar";
```

Both would result in:

```
    Hello foo bar
```

But, what if I want to concatenate without spaces?

Old way would be:

```
    String foo = "foo";
    String newString = "Hello" + "foo" + "bar";
```

Result would be:

```
    Hellofoobar
```

But when I try this at Dart, it gives me an obviously syntax error:

```
    String foo = "foo";
    String newString = "Hello $myString bar";
```

What is the solution to this? Should I use the String.concat? A string buffer? I really liked this new way to concatenate Strings, but I don't think I could use to this kind of situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiple options exist.

First instead of using the + you can just have multiple string literals:

```
String str = 'foo' ' bar ' 'zap'; // any whitespace between literals
```

Secondly if you want to use string interpolation, you can just as the parens to help with scope:

```
String foo = 'foo';
String str = 'Hello${foo}bar';
```